# Electric field calculation with python: keep getting index error (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, index-error

I am working on a computational physics problem using python. The expected output should be a graph with little arrows (using quiver) showing the direction of the electric field at each point inside of a hollow metallic prism with a solid metallic inner conductor. At the inner conductor, the voltage = 1, and at the hollow prism boundaries, the voltage = 0. This is the (somewhat lengthy) code I have:

```
import matplotlib #plotting libraries
import numpy as np #numerical routines
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab #bridge from python to matlab that lets matlab look like a normal python library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #plotting libraries
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D #3D axes 
from copy import deepcopy #deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original
from pylab import * #plotting and numerical routines 

v = [] #creates list for values of v(i,j)
dx = 0.01
dy = 0.01

#initializing boundary conditions:
for i in range(101): 
    row_i = [] #list to store initial values of i and j in
    for j in range(101):
        #i in [35,65] b/c my range is 0-100 for a graph from (-1,1). Thus, each step (in 0-100) has a value of 0.02 (in(-1,1))
        #so since in the graph, the inner conductor is from -0.3,0.3, in time step numbers that is 35 to 65
        if 35<=i<=65 and 35<=j<=65: #boundary for inner conductor
            volt = 1

        #inside (65,99] is all of the space between conductor and prism 
        elif 65<i<=99 or 65<j<=99: #outside of conductor inside prism
            volt = 0
        elif i==0 or i==100 or j==0 or j==100: #metallic prism boundary
            volt = 0
        else:
            volt = 0
        row_i.append(volt) #stores initial values of v in row_i list
    v.append(row_i) #stores the initial values of v in 2d array like list

def update_V(v): #uses initialized values to compute improved estimate for v(i,j)
    dv = 0
    #looping through all points (i,j) except for the boundary
    for i in range(101):
        for j in range(101):
            #pass at boundary:
            if i==0 or i==100 or j==0 or j==100: 
                pass
            #pass at boundary:
            elif 35<=i<=65 and 35<=j<=65:
                pass
            else:
                v_new = (v[i+1][j]+v[i-1][j]+v[i][j+1]+v[i][j-1])/4
                v_old = v[i][j] #assigns value of v(i,j) from previous step as v-old
                dv += abs(v_old - v_new)
                v[i][j] = v_new #after loop goes through calculation for v-new, stores it as the current value for v(i,j)
                #v[i][j] is the value stored in v at the index i and j
    return v, dv

#calls update-v and tests for convergence of dv
def laplace_calculate(v):
    #10^-5 times N for checking 10^-5 at each site
    epsilon = 10**(-5)*100**2

    #initializing dv and N
    dv = 0
    N = 0

    while dv >= epsilon or N <= 10:
        v1, dv = update_V(v) #calling update-v so v creates improved guess of v1
        v2, dv = update_V(v1) #calling update-v again so v1 creates further improved guess of v2
        v = v2
        N += 1

    return v2

Z = laplace_calculate(v)
Ex = deepcopy(Z) #copies the function laplace-calculate
Ey = deepcopy(Z)
Ez = deepcopy(Z)
E = deepcopy(Z)

#electric field values calculation
for i in range(101):
    for j in range(101):
        if i==0 or j==0: #prism boundary on left
            #one sided difference equation for Ex and Ey
            Ex_value = -(v[i+1][j])/dx
            Ey_value = -(v[i][j+1])/dy
            Ex[i][j] = Ex_value #updates Ex-value to Ex list 
            Ey[i][j] = Ey_value #updates Ey-value to Ey list
        elif i==100 or j==100:
            #one sided difference equation for Ex and Ey
            Ex_value = -(v[i-1][j])/dx
            Ey_value = -(v[i][j-1])/dy
            Ex[i][j] = Ex_value
            Ey[i][j] = Ey_value
        elif 35<=i<=65 and 35<=j<=65:
            Ex_value = 0
            Ey_value = 0
            Ex[i][j] = Ex_value
            Ey[i][j] = Ey_value
        else:
            Ex_value = -(v[i+1][j] - v[i-1][j])/(2*dx) 
            Ey_value = -(v[i][j+1] - v[i][j-1])/(2*dy)
            Ex[i][j] = Ex_value
            Ey[i][j] = Ey_value

for i in range(101):
    for j in range(101):
        #just calculates the actual electric field value taken from the x and y values above 
        E_value = np.sqrt(Ex[i][j]**2 + Ey[i][j]**2)
        E[i][j] = E_value

x = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(X, Y, Ey, Ex)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Electric Field')
plt.xticks([-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5],['','-1','','0','','1',''])
plt.yticks([-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5],['','-1','','0','','1',''])
plt.show()
```

However, it keeps throwing an error at line 80:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-f2be5562450c> in <module>
     78             #one sided difference equation for Ex and Ey
     79             Ex_value = -(v[i+1][j])/dx
---> 80             Ey_value = -(v[i][j+1])/dy
     81             Ex[i][j] = Ex_value #updates Ex-value to Ex list
     82             Ey[i][j] = Ey_value #updates Ey-value to Ey list

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand what an index error is, but here, I cannot see how my index is outside of the range of my list. What am I missing? All of the other if/elif loops are in range, as when I comment out the equations for the first if loop inside of my electric field calculations and instead equate them to zero, I get output. I am still very new to python and trying to get a better grasp of it all. Any assistance on this matter whatsoever is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a [mcve]? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: @AMC thank you for posting that link for minimal reproducible examples. That will be very helpful in the future if I have other coding questions. My apologies for the lengthy code. Fortunately, hpaulj (below) pointed out that in the line in question, my [j+1] can get up to 101, when the largest value it can actually go to is 100. Thus, that is why the error occurs. Thanks again for that link, I'm still learning the best ways to post questions on here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` and `j` loops are over `range(101)`, so the smallest value is 0, and the largest 100.

At the line in question

```
Ey_value = -(v[i][j+1])/dy
```

`j+1` can get up to 101.

If `v[i]` is a list with `len` 100, then this index, 100 or 101 is too large.  Valid indexing for a list of this size is 0 to 99 (range(99)).  Same for a numpy array with shape (100,100) (but it would give a different error message).

Comment: Of course! How could I not see that. Thanks so much for your insight, I understand this question should have been posted with the code in a minimal reproducible example. My apologies for that, I am brand new to stack overflow and am still unfamiliar with all the criteria. Thanks so much again!